# What is use of validation.properties for ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL in ESAPI

Tags: java, esapi

I am using ESPAI for SQLInjection prevention in Java.
I am only using `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForSQL(ORACLE_CODEC,queryparam))` method.

If I do not include `validation.properties` in the `esapi.properties` I get `IllegaleStateException`.

Please let me know why encodeForSQL() will require validation.properties.

Answer (score 3):

I'm actually more concerned that you're using ESAPI to stop SQL Injection.  Typically, this is achieved by rewriting the SQL queries in question to parameterized versions, like using `PreparedStatement` or a JPA implementation that uses `PreparedStatement`.  I just want you to be aware, that using ESAPI to encode for SQL only has the design intent for temporary remediation because a particular query is too complex to rewrite during an incident response situation.  If you use `encodeForSQL()` ***just note that it is a band-aid solution for the permanent problem of a poorly written SQL query.***  It should be expected that the query will be rewritten and the need for esapi will go away.

This is because you're not going to get better escaping performance from ESAPI than you will from a properly written `PreparedStatement`.

There are two files ESAPI requires to function properly.  `ESAPI.properties` and `validation.properties`.  These files are needed because in order for most of the classes to load, they need to read options and settings from these files.  You didn't provide a stacktrace, so diagnosing your *exact* problem will be impossible, but if you supply those files, the problem should go away.

[ESAPI.properties](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/src/test/resources/esapi/ESAPI.properties)
[validation.propeties](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/src/test/resources/esapi/validation.properties)

Answer (score 1):

The ESAPI validator does many security checks on input, such as `canonicalisation` and whitelist validation. Note that all of these validation rules are applied *after* `canonicalisation`. 
Double-encoded characters (even with different encodings involved, are never allowed.
To use:

First set up a pattern below. You can choose any name you want, prefixed by the word

```
Validation.Email=^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```

Then you can validate in your code against the pattern like this:

```
Validator.getInstance().getValidDataFromBrowser( "Email", input );
Validator.getInstance().isValidDataFromBrowser( "Email", input );
```