# How to resolve Trust Bound Violation In Date parameter

Tags: java, checkmarx, esapi, secure-coding

Scan shows "Trust Bound Violation" in Session Variables for the below code.

How to sanitize or validate the below `getDate()`?

Not able to use the regular ESAPI validator as `getDate()` is type Timestamp

```
this.queryDate = params.getDate();
```

Comment: Convert timestamp to date and then validate?  Seems easy enough.

Comment: Alternatively you can create your own custom validation for your format:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40435579/557153

Comment: What CWE specifically was associated with this instance? In general, unless the getDate() function is doing really crappy validation, once you have valid java.sql.Timestamp returned, that should generally be a safe object (at least from XSS perspective, which is why I asked about CWE) because of the type safety.

Comment: This has nothing to do with input validation, sanitization, or even XSS.  CWE 501 might explain it in depth.  The key point is that you're taking untrusted data and pushing it into a session.  The detection logic believes you are putting an untrusted value into the session without logical validation. This is not validation of the form of input, it is validation that the value is logically allowed (e.g. maybe this user is not allowed to query for dates before they became a user, etc.).  Not enough code to tell what is going on fully.